# Upload a file to S3 via website, process with Lambda, send file back to user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, frontend

I'm fairly new to AWS.

What I am trying to do is have a static website hosted on S3. The user would be able to upload a zip file to S3 via the front end. Once received, a lambda function would process the zip file and save the output to a single HTML file in another bucket.

How would I then return the processed file back to the right user via the front end? Do I need to send cookies or something along with the original file and somehow send it through lambda too? Additionally, is there a process that would return the processed file back to the original uploader directly from the processing lambda function?

Thanks All,

Appreciate it :)

Comment: It is very high level but you need to use API Gateway, Lambda, and S3. Request file upload through REST endpoint - API gateway then triggers lambda. Lambda processes and saves the file to S3 and generates the Signed URL for the saved file and returns to user. You ned to wait for API response. This will work for small files but not for big files. You can improve this by generating a GUID though JS and save in a cookie so you will have a reference. You need another API to download file based on GUID you send. It is not pretty or ideal but can be done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need API Gateway but it does seem to be on the [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier/?p=ft&z=subnav&loc=2&refid=ft_card) now. I solution I found works for my website is using a **back end** which talks to AWS S3 and AWS Lambda (both on AWS free tier). You can easily host a backend on AWS using AWS Amplify (also on free tier).

When you use AWS, you usually have a back end to talk directly to AWS that has access to your AWS credentials and this provides security because the front end doesn't have access to the AWS credentials.

---

1. In this scenario, the front end asks the back end for a **signed url** to upload the zip file to AWS S3.
2. When the file is uploaded using the signed url, the AWS S3 bucket upload event triggers an AWS lambda which starts processing the zip file.
3. When that file is finished being processed by the lambda, the lambda uploads the processed file to another bucket.
4. Since we are just using HTTP requests and not Pub/Sub (websockets) we would need the front end to regularly poll an endpoint on the back end to check if our processed zip file exists in the destination AWS S3 Bucket, and if so returns a signed url to access that file.
5. Finally the front end uses this second signed url to access the processed zip file.